# Filter kafka message from topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a spring batch job which will write messages into a Kafka topic. Now I need to test whether specific messages are present in the kafka topic how do i achieve this using spring boot

I am anticipating to use the Kafka stream will this be useful

Answer (score 0):

Searching Kafka topics requires consuming the whole topic. Ideally, you'd dump the topic into an index database instead, and search that.

You can use Kafka Streams, but it doesn't return true/false and stop on single messages.

Start a regular consumer. You can use `spring-kafka` w/ `@KafkaListener`, and you can then write an if statement to check message content.